# Python amount of days in a month with a given year and month?

Tags: python

I am working on an application that asks the user for a year and a month number (most likely using `int(raw_input())`), then it displays the amount of days in that month, bearing in mind leap years.

Is there a built-in or existing implementation for this problem?

I am currently using Python 2.2.3

Comment: That's what it does, is it? Wait, what are we talking about again?

Comment: How is this in any way whatsoever 'too broad'!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all sorts of things with the [`calendar`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/calendar.html) module:

```
import calendar

year = int(raw_input('Enter year: '))
month = int(raw_input('Enter month number: '))

print(calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1])
```

This considers leap years just fine, too.

Example:

```
Enter year: 2012
Enter month number: 2
29
```

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for [calendar.monthrange](http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange):

```
>>> calendar.monthrange(2014, 2)
(5, 28)
```

Looks like February had 28 days this year, and started on a Saturday (0 is Monday.)

Answer (score -3):

```
value = int(raw_input("Please enter a year and a month number:"))
print "There are 30 days in that month +/- 1 with ~99.93% confidence."
print "(bearing in mind February will be outside that range for 3 months in every 48)."
```

Edit:

Come come, my friendly  downvoters, consider my proposal again, please.

With it you may inform your customers and coworkers of the number of 
days in a year and be perfectly correct for 16 months in every 48. As well as that, for another 29 months in every 48, the answer will still be within *a fifteenth* of the desired value.

This is not the 1600s where you have to rely on astrolabes and teams of astronomer-monks, this is precision modern computing with high tolerances. A fifteenth!

If that isn't enough for you, I invite you to consider that you will be able to answer to within a fifteenth of the 'correct' number with *over 99% confidence*, an answer spoken with confidence and backed by mathematics and modern day electronics, a winning combination and your customers will adore it.

The answer is compact, taking minimal space on your storage systems, it's concise without being terse, compact but not needlessly complicated, brief yet sacrifices nothing of value.

You are welcome to give it any test, there is no obligation to buy!

Comment: Why are you converting it to an int if you're not dealing with the input at all? Might as well leave it as a string.

Comment: Why @TankorSmash, that was part of the requirements specification! I would get nowhere if I ignored that.

Comment: Your enthusiasm is infectious. Splitting hairs though, it merely suggested the idea of using int, no requirement listed.